# Pycharm lost connection between views and template

Tags: python, django, pycharm

One day I discovered that one Django application lost the connection between views and a template. I checked the whole project and this problem got only one application.

There is no connection in views between the function and the template. There is no code highlighting in the template, no code completion in templates, and the template does not recognize tags, for example:

```
{% url%}, <script src="{% static '...'%}"> </ script>, {% extends "base.html"%}
```

and so on.

The application is correctly written in INSTALLED_APPS, does have a namespace in the urls and works correctly in the browser if the project is launched. The only one thing have changed: I recently had updated PyCharm to: (PyCharm 2019.1.2 (Professional Edition)
Build #PY-191.7141.48, built on May 7, 2019)

Comment: PyCharm is only editor/IDE and it has nothing to do with Python and Django.

Comment: I agree, but in this case it does not fulfill its functions as an editor and IDE. There is no code highlighting, no code completion, and so on.

Comment: do you have any plugins that need to be manually updated after updating pycharm? I have similar issues with other things when i update pycharm. Goto preference and plugins

Comment: I only have the "basic" plugins installed:
CSV Plugin,
Material Theme UI (I don't use it),
Ideolog
And that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely one of the template parent folders is marked as Resource Root (right-click in the project tree -> Mark Directory as ... -> Resource Root). This effectively disables any special template highlighting in all child files. To quickly find all Resource Roots in your project check **Settings | Project ... | Project Structure**.

If this was the case please vote for the dedicated ticket in PyCharms bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-28428 as it will be nice to redisign this feature making it more discoverable.